# Where is a good place to put store system wide resources such as db connections in Play2?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I heard that Play2 resembles a lot Ruby on Rails. There I would place generally available resources in a constant and initialize it writing an `initialiser`.

Is there a similar technique in Play2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala you could store them in an object's member as val or lazy val. I would do initialization in the Global object's onStart.

Answer (score 2):

depending on the state of the resource, if it's constant, you can put them in a enum object. it if's persistent information, you can put in conf/evolution/default/1.sql, and Play will automatically load it when you initialize everything. you can put configuration constants in conf/application.conf, if it's strings, you can put in message file.